# How can you use SFPro font in Xcode for deployment target 9.3?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Xcode doesn't come with SFPro by default if we set deployment target as 9.3. The system font is SF. 
I am doubtful if loading SFPro font manually will work even if I have not set deployment target as 11.

Answer (score 1):

You can download the fonts here: https://developer.apple.com/fonts/

Add the font files to your project and declare them in Project Info settings with `Fonts provided by application`:

[image]

Then use the font with code like this (for example):

```
    if let customFont = UIFont(name: "SFProDisplay-Regular", size: 32) {
        theLabel.font = customFont
    }
```

To find the actual names of the fonts, you can use this code:

```
    for family in UIFont.familyNames {

        let sName: String = family as String
        print("family: \(sName)")

        for name in UIFont.fontNames(forFamilyName: sName) {
            print("name: \(name as String)")
        }
    }
```